# Running jQuery file in Wordpress admin and executing it after AJAX

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

the task is fairly "simple", but I am annoyed with it for whole today. In Woocommerce admin order preview, I want to change class, to the number, where quantity is greater than 1.

For this purpose, I have made following things.

1. Loaded the script (if I open developer console, the pathway is correct):

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
function add_my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jqueryforadmin', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/wp-admin.js');
}
```

2. In the wp-admin.js I have added the jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.wc-order-preview-table__column--quantity').filter(function(index){
    return parseInt(this.innerHTML) > 1;
}).css({'color':'blue', 'text-decoration':'underline'});
});
```

The problem is that the code doesn't work. I remember, that the order preview is loaded via Ajax. Not even sure, if the code is right (because of the compatability mode I am not familiar with). Is there any way to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out

1) I forgot to include jQuery as dependency as suggested by thingEvery.

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_jquery_script' );
function admin_jquery_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jqueryforadmin', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/wp-admin.js', array('jquery'));
}
```

2) The trick was in using `.ajaxComplete`

```
jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
    jQuery('.wc-order-preview-table__column--quantity').filter(function(index){
        return parseInt(this.innerHTML) > 1;
    }).css({'color':'red'});        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include jquery as a dependency.

`wp_enqueue_script( 'jqueryforadmin', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/wp-admin.js', array( 'jquery' ) );`

[wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)

Comment: Thank you, added the dependency, but still it doesn't change anything.